# Concurrent programming in Python and Qt

Tags: python, qt, concurrency, pyside

I wrote a small program to evaluate the state of cellular automata and paint it on the screen. I have dual-core PC, so in order to increase efficiency I decided to make calculations in two threads. I made my own implementations of QThread, like so:

```
clacc MyThread(QThread):
    def run(self):
        ...
```

Then I'm making two instances of this class and calling them:

```
thread1 = MyThread()
thread2 = MyThread()

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

When I opened the Task Manager, I found that they're executing one after another: thread1 first, then thread2, then thread1 again and so on.
Question is: is there a way to invoke them so they will work independently, on different cores and in one moment of time, not one after another?

Comment: Depends on what your threads actually do. Looks like either they simply don't take enough CPU to be scheduled on two cores, or they are using a shared resource and are advancing in lockstep because of this.

Comment: you may want to take a look into this: http://blip.tv/carlfk/mindblowing-python-gil-2243379 . Threading in Python is quite...awkward, to say the least

Comment: @Evgeni - what you say is true, and in addition to that `QThreads` also have their [own threading model and issues](http://qt-project.org/doc/thread-basics.html). @aga - you should look into that as well

Comment: which Task Manager are you using so that you can see threads are executing one after another here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use threads, you can't increase efficiency as you wish, because it won't do paarallelization. You need to do multiprocessing. To do that, you can use the mulltiprocessing  module, which works like threading module :

```
import multiprocessing

class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def run(self):
        # new process context
```

You won't share the same context so you can't communicate directly by methods calls. I advise you to use some "message queue" system like : multiprocessing.Queue or zeromq (great great lib !).

If you look at "Ventillator" zmq design pattern you'll see it do exactly what you need : paralellize workers.